# Fiddler stopped capturing SOAP requests

Tags: wcf, soap, fiddler

I have a WCF Service on local machine, deployed at localhost/XYZ, and when I am consuming it from a locally hosted site, the requests/response(SOAP) are not getting captured by fiddler.

Though earlier it was happening properly, not sure what messed it up.

I came to know that earlier it was working because, I ran that client in debug mode of VS, that is through IIS express. But when hosted on IIS it was not getting captured.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your WCF web service address is http: //localhost:5555/MyService.

Make sure your WCF client request is going to the Fiddler proxy port (usually 8888), not to actual port upon which your program's running - for example 5555. Also make sure you have edited the Fiddler custom rules (see below) to capture your inbound requests on port 8888 and transfer those requests to the actual port (5555) your program listens on.

That's typically the problem I've run into.

Go edit your custom rules, go to the Fiddler rules menu: then click CustomRules. This should open Notepad with your CustomRules.js (java script) inside. Add a rule like this to the Static function OnBeforeRequest() section:

```
if (oSession.host=="127.0.0.1:8888") {
  oSession.host="127.0.0.1:5555";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I would try this, but as a workaround I came to know that when I was debugging my client through IIS express, it was getting captured, but not when hosted on IIS.